# How to release a SAFEARRAY within another SAFEARRAY

Tags: .net, com, mfc, interop, safearray

I am using a .NET component from MFC/C++ through a COM interface (using .NET Interop). The interface contains structures containing arrays (resulting in SAFEARRAYS in COM).

I am having trouble releasing the SAFEARRAYs in the correct way. When running the application, the application will crash at the second SafeArrayDestroy. So, will the inner SAFEARRAY be deleted, when deleting the outer SAFAARRAY?
Any other thoughts?

Thanks!

The C# interface looks like this:

```
public struct structVersionCondition
{
    public Int32 m_val;
}
public struct structVersion
{
    public structVersionCondition[] m_VersionConditions;
}
public struct structVersions
{
    public structVersion[] m_Version;
}

public interface TextStore_Interface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    bool GetVersionRef(out structVersions versions);
}
```

The resulting COM IF is called from MFC/C++ and looks like this:

```
m_pIF->GetVersionRef(&ver, &retVal);
SafeArrayAccessData(ver.m_Version, (void**)&pValsOuter);
//..Get Lower and Upper bound calculate number of elements
for (int i=0; i<elem_no; ++i){
    SafeArrayAccessData(pValsOuter[i].m_VersionConditions, (void**)&pValsInner);
    //operate on the structVersionCondition[] SAFEARRAY trough pValsInner
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(pValsOuter[i].m_VersionConditions);
    SafeArrayDestroy(pValsOuter[i].m_VersionConditions);
}
SafeArrayUnaccessData(ver.m_Version);
SafeArrayDestroy(ver.m_Version); //Exception is thrown here!
```

Regards
John

Comment: You destroyed the m_VersionConditions array but your forgot to set the pointer to NULL.  So destroying m_Version will try to destroy the inner array again.  Kaboom.

Comment: Setting the SAFEARRAY pointers to NULL after calling SafeArrayDestroy, seemed to do the trick! Thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see and I understand the SafeArrayDestroy function you are not responsible to free arrays stored inside the SafeArray.

SafeArrayDestroy frees all memory associated with its stored members. Its like VARIANTs stored inside the SafeArray. VariantClear is called. also IDispatch pointers are released.

SafeAray handles all COM types in a correct way.

But in fact: I never tried you construct. When I have data nested in an SafeArray I always use a VARIANT.

The documentation isn't very clear: [SafeArrayDestroy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Destroys an existing array descriptor and all of the data in the
>   array. If objects are stored in the array, Release is called on each
>   object in the array.

And

> Safe arrays of variant will have the VariantClear function called on
>   each member and safe arrays of BSTR will have the SysFreeString
>   function called on each element. IRecordInfo::RecordClear will be
>   called to release object references and other values of a record
>   without deallocating the record.

Comment: Yeah the documentation is open to interpretation. The advice offered by Hans Passant did the trick. 
However it seems that if the outer SAFEARRAY sees that the inner SAFEARRAY is NULL it will not try to free the inner SAFEARRAY, but maybe that means that the outer SAFEARRAY will free the inner SAFEARRAY if the inner SAFEARRAY is nut NULL?!
Anyway, I feel better knowing that i have personally released all SAFEARRAYs myself!